# Calculate pixel distance from centre of image

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

---

## Problem

I have an image, `n` pixel wide, `m` pixel tall. Both of these numbers are even. Pixels are squares. Pixel values are in a numpy array.

I need to calculate the distance from each pixel's centre to the centre of the image. Ie the pixels just next to the centre should have associated values `sqrt(2)/2`. If the image is like a chess-board, the pixel corresponding to g6 square should have associated distance value should be (2.5^2+1.5^2)^0.5=2.91

---

## My solution

I have achieved the task by the following code:

```
image=np.zeros([2,4]) # let's say this is my image
df = pd.DataFrame(image)

distances = \
pd.DataFrame(
df.apply(
    lambda row: (row.index+0.5-len(df.index)/2)**2,axis=0).to_numpy()+\
df.T.apply(
    lambda row: (row.index+0.5-len(df.columns)/2)**2,axis=0).T.to_numpy())\
    .apply(np.sqrt).to_numpy()
```

`distances` will be:

```
array([[1.58113883, 0.70710678, 0.70710678, 1.58113883],
       [1.58113883, 0.70710678, 0.70710678, 1.58113883]])
```

As expected.

---

## Question

Is there a better way? I would appreciate a shorter, more-numpy oriented, or more transparent method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know any specific algorithms to do this except this straightforward implementation in Numpy, that is, using the [indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html#numpy-indices) (creates array of indices from shape of array) and [linalg.norm](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html#numpy-linalg-norm) (calculates norms) functions. Note we also use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) by indexing new dimensions in `center[:,None,None]` (necessary because of `indices` intrinsic output shape).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Numpy function
def np_function(image):
    center = np.array([(image.shape[0])/2, (image.shape[1])/2])
    distances = np.linalg.norm(np.indices(image.shape) - center[:,None,None] + 0.5, axis = 0)

    return distances

# Pandas function
def pd_function(image):
    df = pd.DataFrame(image)
    
    distances = \
    pd.DataFrame(
    df.apply(
        lambda row: (row.index+0.5-len(df.index)/2)**2,axis=0).to_numpy()+\
    df.T.apply(
        lambda row: (row.index+0.5-len(df.columns)/2)**2,axis=0).T.to_numpy())\
        .apply(np.sqrt).to_numpy()
        
    return distances
```

For a 4000x6000 image, Numpy's method is more than one order of magnitude faster than the original function in my computer. You could also just compute the distances from the center to one octant and then copy the results conveniently to the remaining octants (exploiting simmetry), but this will probably be only worth for big images imho.

Answer (score 3):

A more transparent method would be first to define the center of your image, i.e something like

1. Read your array as an image in openCV :

   ```
    img = cv2.imread("inputImage")
    height, width = img.shape

    x_center=(width/2)
    y_center=(height/2)
   ```
2. Then for each pixels in your numpy/image array you can compute the distance between each pixel of your numpy array and the above center by computing the euclidean distance:

   D = dist.euclidean((xA, yA), (x_center, y_center))

PS : You can simply use img.shape from numpy but openCV gives you many method related to distance computing.

Comment: What's xA & yA?

Comment: xA and yA are the coordinates of the pixel from which you want to compute the distance to the center

Comment: So you will pass every pixels of you numpy array and compute its distance to the center defined above.

Comment: Would you be able to provide code for that in your answer? I would like the distance of every pixel.